# Unable to run android emulator through linux command line

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

I tried to start android emulator through command line but I got the following error message

```
NAND: could not write file /tmp/android-root/emulator-NDDWIW, File exists
```

Please advice what has to be done. I wanted to run the android emulator in headless mode.

Comment: Do you use sudo before the command?

Comment: I used the following command: sudo ./emulator -avd my_android -no-window -no-skin